# Templates escaping in Kotlin multiline strings

Tags: string, kotlin, syntax

If I want to use `$` sign in multiline strings, how do I escape it?

```
val condition = """ ... $eq ... """
```

`$eq` is parsed as a reference to a variable. How to escape `$`, so that it will not be recognized as reference to variable? (Kotlin M13)

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33461403/escape-something-in-a-kotlin-string

Comment: `sed 's/\$/${'"'"'$'"'"'}/g'` (in case those Kotlin string literals are automatically generated by something else)

Comment: Since $ is already magic in raw strings, and has to notice whether there's a {} or a variable name after it, it's a bit of a shame they didn't simply allow $ to escape itself: $$ would just become $ and if you wanted $ before $price, you'd write """$$$price"""

Answer (score 112, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-literals)

> A raw string is delimited by a triple quote ("""), contains no
> escaping and can contain newlines and any other character

You would need to use a standard string with newlines

```
" ...\n \$eq \n ... "
```

or you could use the literal representation

```
""" ... ${'$'}eq ... """
```

Comment: too bad there is no way to escape $ in raw strings... when using single line syntax, it's a bit ugly and not readable... If only they had something like "really raw and dumb string", which would ignore everything including $ templates...

Comment: yes, like singlequote: 'aaa${bbb}'  or ''' sssssssss'''

Comment: `\$` does **not** work in multiline strings. Only `${'$'}` does. Because the backslash is interpreted as a literal backslash and not as an escape.

Comment: So groovy has triple single-quote, http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string, which does not interpolate, wish kotlin supported this.

Comment: Both variants `"x"` and `"""x"""` are string literals. I would propose to change "or you could use the literal representation" to "or you could use a raw string"

Answer (score 13):

Funny, but that works:

```
val eq = "\$eq"

print("""... $eq  ..."""")   // just like you asked :D
```

Actually, if `eq` is a number (a price, or sth), then you probably want to calculate it separately, and an additional external calculation as I suggested won't hurt.

Comment: $eq here is recognized as variable which I don't want. I want all syntax to be ignored.

Comment: For me that would be a workaround, certainly the syntax is better than `..${'$}eq..``
See for yourself, though

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer below, you can make this a little neater with a helper object, but the really cool thing is that you can define the set of `$`-strings you allow, which in the case of a defined set of operators (like in Mongo) it means you get some typo-protection.

Answer (score 7):

In the case where you know ahead of time what `$`-variables you want (like when querying Mongo, as it looks like you might be doing), you can create a little helper object that defines those variables. You also get some protection against accidentally misspelling one of your operators, which is neat.

```
object MongoString {
    inline operator fun invoke(callback: MongoString.() -> String) = callback()

    val eq = "\$eq"
    val lt = "\$lt"
    // ... and all the other operators ...
}

fun test() {
    val query = MongoString { """{"foo": {$lt: 10}}""" }
}
```

I wrote simple versions for update and query strings for mongo here: https://gist.github.com/Yona-Appletree/29be816ca74a0d93cdf9e6f5e23dda15