# Escape ${something} in a Kotlin String

Tags: kotlin

What is the correct way of defining a Kotlin string that includes the characters for declaring a template substitution, but *not* have this evaluated as a template?

For example: `"${something}"` just treated as an ordinary string.

I would like to use the Spring value annotation:

```
@Value("${some.property}) lateinit var foobar : String?
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993586/templates-escaping-in-kotlin-multiline-strings

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This works for me:

```
val s = "\${foo}"
println("s = ${s}") // prints s = ${foo}
```

The [documented way](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) also works fine:

```
val s = "${'$'}{foo}"
println("s = ${s}") // prints s = ${foo}
```

Comment: It seems that both `"\${foo}"` and `$\{foo}` work. Which one is better?

Comment: For multiline strings: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32993586/templates-escaping-in-kotlin-multiline-strings/32994616

Comment: Both ways are documented. The only difference between your two solutions is, that the latter works in escaped strings (one double-quote, escape sequences supported) and also in raw strings (three double-quotes, escape sequences do not work). In escaped strings I'd always use the backslash-variant as it is cleaner and probably more performant.